# Bridge existing LAN network with Mikrotik hap Lite

Tags: networking

I have existing network on 192.168.0.1 subnet, now I bought Mikrotik hap Lite which I want to use to extend existing network, and be able to connect clients on Mikrotik both wired (printer) and wirelles ( smartphone, notebook ) but all devices must see each other. First modem/router will be used as DHCP server and its address is 192.168.0.1. How should I configure Mikrotik to achieve mentioned behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setup `hap Lite` to use a subnet of your `192.168.0.0`/`255.255.255.0`(?) primary network and connect `hap Lite` WAN to your `primary router` LAN.

If you prefer DHCP usage:

- Setup `hap Lite` WAN port to get IP address from DHCP.
- Bind a `hap Lite` WAN IP address with its MAC address on your `primary router` DHCP configuration.
- Choose `hap Lite` subnet from outside of DHCP range.
- Add route to your `primary router` to push network traffic to `hap Lite` LAN subnet trough `hap Lite` WAN IP.

If you prefer static addressing:

- Setup `hap Lite` WAN port to unique IP address in your `primary router` LAN.
- Choose `hap Lite` subnet as unique IP range in your `primary router` LAN.
- Add route to your `primary router` to push network traffic to `hap Lite` LAN subnet trough `hap Lite` WAN IP.

You can mix:

- Static `hap Lite` WAN port IP address.
- DHCP on `hap Lite` LAN.